# Star shaped network with directed links from center

Tags: netlogo

I want to generate star topology of a network with directed links from the central node to the other nodes. I have created star network with links to the central node from the external nodes, but I am not able to direct the links from the centre to other nodes.

```
 directed-link-breed [Ls L]

 to star
   ca
   nw:generate-star turtles Ls 100 ; using link breed
   [
      set color red
      fd random 15
      set shape "circle"
      ask links [set color yellow]
   ]

   nw:generate-star turtles Ls-to 100 ; it does not work
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to control the direction that `nw:generate-star` will generate the links in. However, it's quite easy to generate the star yourself:

```
to star
  ca
  create-turtles 100 [
    set color red
    fd random 15
    set shape "circle"
  ]
  ask turtle 0 [
    setxy 0 0 
    create-Ls-to other turtles [ set color yellow ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.